# While trying to prove the continuity of a 2-variable function, I got stuck with the proof of the existence of the limit

Tags: calculus, limits, multivariable-calculus, continuity

$$ \lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)} {x^3 - xy^2 \over x^2 + y^2} $$

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The standard tool is "polar coordinates".

Comment: @Crostul That's not "The standard tool."  It's a tool and an unnecessary one, especially here.

Comment: @MarkViola agree. Mark Viola you are great! I am so fed up this polar coordinate concept that has nothing to do with abstract nature of calculus. I am so happy to find a real fan and supporter of the precise definition of limit.

Comment: @krszyoscezio Yes.  Transforming to polar coordinates is a viable way forward,  is not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:**

$$\left|\frac{x^3-xy^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|=|x|\,\underbrace{\left|\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|}_{\le 1}\le |x|$$

Comment: Thank you! Should I say that our initial limit is less or equal to its absolute value and then use the Squeeze Thm? Am I right?

Comment: You're welcome.  My pleasure.  For all $\epsilon>0$, $\left|\frac{x^3-xy^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|<\epsilon$ whenever $|x|\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2}<\delta=\epsilon$.

Comment: But, change the numerator to $x^2y+4xy^2$, and a different variant is needed. Still factor out the $x$, but then note that $|x|,|y|\le\sqrt{x^2+y^2}$, and so $$\left|\frac{xy+4y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|\le \frac{5(x^2+y^2)}{x^2+y^2} = 5.$$ Lots of variants ...

Comment: why $\underbrace{\left|\frac{x^2-y^2}{x^2+y^2}\right|}_{\le 1}$?

Comment: @gbox $|x^2-y^2|\le x^2+y^2$ is a consequence of the triangle inequality.

Comment: @TedShifrin I'm not sure of the relevance of your comment.

Comment: The triangle inequality is in general more powerful than having the negative sign to take advantage of. I wasn't criticizing. Just trying to help educate.

Comment: @TedShifrin Ah, I see.  In that case, thank you for the constructive comment.